# POST not posting correctly

Tags: swift, post, response

Using Swift here.

I can't for the life of me, figure out why I can't get a proper response code back from my POST  function. Any tips on figuring out why this isn't working?

I checked the resource URL already and it should be all gouda here too. Let me know what I am missing here or a point in the right direction helps a ton too.

```
func sendEmail(_ emailToSend:Email, completion: @escaping(Result<Email,APIError>) -> Void){
    do{
        var request = URLRequest(url: resourceURL)
        
        
        let body: [String: String] = ["email": emailToSend.email]
        
        let finalBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(body)
        
    
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = finalBody
        
        
        let dataTask =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, _ in
            
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,httpResponse.statusCode == 200,
                  let jsonData = data else {
                completion(.failure(.responseProblem))
                print(completion(.failure(.responseProblem)))
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                do {
                    print("Decoding Email..." )
                    let messageData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Email.self, from: jsonData)
                    completion(.success(messageData))
                    print("Completed Successfully with \(completion(.success(messageData)))")
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.decodingProblem))
                    print("Failed Decoding \(completion(.failure(.decodingProblem)))")
                    
                }
            }
        
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    } catch {
        completion(.failure(.encodingProblem))
    }
    
}
```

- I did change the `dataTask` to point to the `URLresource` instead of the request before, but that didn't work.
- I am expecting a code 200 response here from this post request.

Comment: could you add `print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` just before `guard let httpResponse = ...` and 
show us what it prints. Also could you show the code for the `Email` struct that you are decoding.

Comment: There is no SwiftUI here -- this is just Swift

Comment: Why are you ignoring errors?

Comment: Provide the specs of the endpoint you are trying to reach. Otherwise how can anyone guess why your post request is incorrect?

Comment: Turns out there were more issues in the server side of things. Thanks again for the comments everyon! especially @workingdogsupportUkraine